# Asset pipeline creates empty Javascript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I recently moved our QA Rails application on to a new server due to a corrupt disk. However the asset pipeline now creates an empty Javascript file. This does not happen locally when running `rake assets:precompile`.

The file created is called public/assets/application-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js`

The "e3b0c442" hash is the SHA-256 for an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we where using our own Javascript compressor, not the default one. Our compressor shells out to `ugliferjs`. Because it is a new server the latest version of `ugliferjs` was installed, via npm.

However one of the options we where passing to `ugliferjs` was no longer supported. It seems the errors, somewhere, was being silently swallowed.

Checking for the version of `uglifierjs` and passing different options for each fixed the issue.